# How to freeze first two columns and border in html table?

Tags: html, css

I want freeze first two columns and its border in html table. I went through multiple post in stackoverflow. I am able to freeze the columns but border is keep moving. how to freeze table border?

also header border also keep moving. Is there any way to freeze the borders along with columns in HTML, CSS?

Thanks in advance...

```css
.view {
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .sticky-col {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .first-col {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  
  .second-col {
    width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    left: 100px;
  }

  table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<div class="view">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="sticky-col first-col">Number</th>
            <th class="sticky-col second-col">First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Employer</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">1</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Mark</td>
            <td>Ham</td>
            <td>Micro</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">2</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Jacob</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Adob Adob Adob AdobAdob Adob Adob Adob Adob</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">3</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify a little your CSS part:

```css
.view {
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .sticky-col {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .first-col {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  
  .second-col {
    width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    left: 104px; /* you have to count the first-col width => your border width */
  }

/* separate table part and td, th part */
  td, th {
     border: 1px solid black;
  }
  table {
     border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="view">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="sticky-col first-col">Number</th>
            <th class="sticky-col second-col">First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Employer</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">1</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Mark</td>
            <td>Ham</td>
            <td>Micro</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">2</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Jacob</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Adob Adob Adob AdobAdob Adob Adob Adob Adob</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">3</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```